# How to disable a single row in a datawindow?

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

Can anybody help me that how can I protect individual column of an individual row, though my datawindow has more than one row. I am writing a code like this:

```
dw_1.Modify("column_name.protect = '1'")
```

However it is making all my rows disabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have some sort of conditional statement for the particular row/column you wish to protect.  One way is to have an additional field you set programatically like.

```
dw_1.setitem(1,"protect_me","Y")
```

Then in your other column you set an expression on the protect property like:

```
if(protect_me[0] = "Y", 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cane make it like :
    dw_1.SetRedraw ( FALSE )

```
ls_modstring = as_columnnane + ".background.color = '" + String(RGB( 255, 255, 255 )) + &
                    "~tIf( protection = 1," + String(RGB( 192, 192, 192 )) + "," + &
                    String(RGB( 255, 255, 255)) + ")'"
dw_1.Modify( ls_modstring )

ls_modstring = as_columnnane + ".protect = '0 ~tIf( protection = 1, 1, 0 )'"
dw_1.Modify( ls_modstring )

dw_1.SetRedraw ( TRUE )
```

Where as_columnnane  is the column name.

Comment: It appears as though you have added a numeric column called 'protection' and are using it exactly the same way as I suggested earlier.

Comment: this will too make all rows protect/unprotect, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Santosh Kumar Dutta,

I suggest you use datawindow protect properties instead of modify syntax.
could you please give us exact small code based on what field or condition you want to protect.

from pb_developer