# How to disable the selected rows

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow, data-objects

I have a data window with a checkbox. I want to disable the selected rows. How can I do that? Also, please explain to me the code below. I saw it online and it works fine but it only disable the first selected row.  Thank you

```
dw_unreportedprall.object.sel.protect = '0~tif(GetRow()=' + string(ll_ctr) + ',1,0)'
```

Comment: Please check this question: [How to disable a single row in a datawindow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885291/how-to-disable-a-single-row-in-a-datawindow)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the variable 'll_ctr' holds the value for the row you are checking.  If so you could try:

```
...'0~tif(IsSelected(' + string(ll_ctr) + '),1,0)'
```

Your code only works on a single row because the GetRow() method only gives you the current row (the one with focus) in a datawindow.

Comment: Thanks again sir Matt. Yes ll_ctr holds the row of the checked row, and I tried isSelected but still disabling the 1st checked row only. Btw, I have an expression column if (sel = 'y', 1, 0).  Sel is the name of checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the last two number

```
dw_unreportedprall.object.sel.protect = '0~tif(GetRow()=' + string(ll_ctr) + ',0,1)'
```

It will protect all but not the new row.